# Add library org.springframework.boot.context. ... 2.4.2 to classpath in every mouldes of project

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have multimodules maven project that all of modules inherit from parent module that contains all dependencies. Whenever I create a new module and starting to write some codes, some annotation dos not recognized and following message shows to me to add library to classpath.

```
add library org.springframework.boot.context. ...2.4.2 to classpath
```

Why this happens whereas new module inherit parent module?

Parent pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>app</module>
        <module>post</module>
        <module>common</module>
        <module>siam</module>
        <module>tax</module>
        <module>civilregistration</module>
    </modules>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>ir.shaparak.sm</groupId>
    <artifactId>servicemanager</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>servicemanager</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <testcontainers.version>1.15.1</testcontainers.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->

        <!--should be excluded, because other modules extend from this pom and we need tomcat only in app module -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>-->
        <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
       

    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
                <artifactId>testcontainers-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${testcontainers.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>
                                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            </exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

moudle pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>servicemanager</artifactId>
        <groupId>ir.shaparak.sm</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ir.shaparak.sm.tax</groupId>
    <artifactId>tax</artifactId>


</project>
```

Comment: Does it contain dependencies or dependency management (different sections with a while different purpose!).

Comment: No actually... ......

Comment: That isn't really an answer to my question. According to your question you have a parent that includes all dependencies (which I doubt). Hence are those "dependencies" in a `<dependencies>` section or `<dependencyManagement>` section in your parent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Its inside <dependencies> section.

Comment: Again I really doubt it. Please add the relevant `pom.xml`s (parent and module) to your question.

Comment: Well, I added pom files

Comment: Then it should work, or you are using annotations/classes that aren't part of the dependencies you have added. Also there is no 5.5.1 version of Spring Boot so that is weird already.

Comment: Yes it works, but my question is that why I have to add to class path in moudle when I use parent classes whereas module inherit parent. also I changed to 2.4.2, it was my fault

Comment: If it isn't on the classpath you are either using classes from a dependency **not** defined in the parent or you have imported it badly into your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Simply should reimport maven in Intelij, then no need to add libaray to classpath.